# Latitude E6410 - Screen flickering on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, display, dell-latitude, refresh-rate

On Windows 8, my Latitude E6410 screen (1440x900 - 60Hz - NVidia NVS3100M) is flickering. If I turn off the laptop for 30 minutes and turn it back on, there's no flickering but it eventually start again after 10-15 minutes. The flickering seems more present at the top and bottom of the screen.

I already updated the graphic card drivers, bios, etc. Nothing seems to fix the issue. To prove that it isn't a hardware issue, when I reinstalled Windows 7 I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue.  Hoping that an updated driver from Nvidia will fix the problem.

Comment: See the post from MKPL here: http://commweb-ps3.us.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19464795.aspx?PageIndex=6  If your screen is a Samsung with hardware ID SEC5442, it probably needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Contacted Dell, that updated the Intel Graphics driver and now its fixed.

[Here is the Link for the driver from Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/confirm.aspx?httpDown=http://downloadmirror.intel.com/21180/a08/win8_64_1528.zip&lang=eng&Dwnldid=21180&DownloadType=Drivers&OSFullname=Windows%208,%2064-bit*&ProductID=3319)

I'm having the same issue.

At first, after initial Windows 8 upgrade, the Dell 15z screen would flicker and shake.

After installing the new Nvidia graphics driver, the screen seems to be dimming and attempting to auto adjust the brightness, possibly through the sensors.

When I connect to external monitor, there are no dimming or flickering issues.

Will be contacting tech support soon, but they will probably just say they won't support win 8 on my laptop since I bought it with win 7

Comment: I did contact support a couple of days ago about this and they told me to re-install Windows 7.

Comment: try that Enable Adaptive Brightness in power options

Comment: It's already enabled in all power plan options.

Comment: I think the problem is that the adaptive brightness is sensing not working properly and adjusting the screen at undesired times. I have tried disabling this setting, but there is still a slight flicker

Comment: Nope it was the driver, I added the link to the answer above

Comment: This isn't answering the question. The question was about E6410 with NVidia drivers.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your onboard graphics chip might be starting to fail, possibly from overheating.  Have you opened up the laptop to clean out dust and debris?  Also, is the laptop still under support?  You might be able to get a replacement.